# writing to character device file is causing list_del() or list_add() corruption. How do I fix it?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am following LDD3. I have implemented the read and write functionality for the scull module. whenever I run `echo hello > /dev/scull0` to test the write function, I get `list_add()` / `list_del()` corruption and a stack trace.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>

#define SCULL_DEV_NO 4

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int scull_major = 0;
static int scull_minor = 0;
static int scull_nr_devs = 4;
static int scull_qset_val = 1000;
static int scull_quantum_val = 4000;

module_param(scull_major, int, S_IRUGO);

static dev_t dev = 0;

struct scull_qset {
    void **data;
    struct scull_qset * next;
};

struct scull_dev {
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct scull_qset *data;
    int qset;
    unsigned long size;
    int quantum;
    unsigned int access_key;
    struct semaphore sem;
};

int scull_trim(struct scull_dev *dev) {
    struct scull_qset *dptr, *next;
    int i;
    int qset =  dev->qset;
    for (dptr = dev->data; dptr; dptr = next) {
        if (dptr->data){
            for(i = 0; i < qset; i++) {
                kfree(dptr->data[i]);
            }
            kfree(dptr->data);
            dptr->data = NULL;
        }
        next = dptr->next;
        kfree(dptr);
    }

    dev->data = NULL;
    dev->qset = scull_qset_val;
    dev->size = 0;
    dev->quantum = scull_quantum_val;
    return 0;
}

int scull_open(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp) {
    struct scull_dev * dev;
    dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev);

    filp->private_data = dev;

    if((filp->f_flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_WRONLY) {
        scull_trim(dev);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Opened device %d\n", iminor(inode));

    return 0;
}

int scull_release(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Released device %d\n", iminor(inode));
    return 0;
}

struct scull_qset* scull_follow(struct scull_dev *dev, int item) {
    struct scull_qset* ptr = dev->data;
    struct scull_qset* rptr = NULL;

    for(int i=0; i<item+1; i++) {
        pr_info("DEBUG: ptr = %p, ptr->next = %p\n", ptr, ptr ? ptr->next : NULL);
        if(ptr == NULL) {
            ptr = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_qset), GFP_KERNEL);
            if (ptr == NULL)
                return NULL;
            memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(struct scull_qset));
            ptr->data = NULL;
            ptr->next = NULL;
        }

        rptr = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return rptr;
}

ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    ssize_t retval = 0;
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data;
    struct scull_qset *dptr;
    int quantum = dev->quantum, qset = dev->qset;
    int itemsize = quantum * qset;
    int item, s_pos, q_pos, rest;

    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    if (*f_pos >= dev->size)
        goto out;
    if (*f_pos + count > dev->size)
        count = dev->size - *f_pos;

    item = (long)*f_pos / itemsize;
    rest = (long)*f_pos % itemsize;
    s_pos = rest / quantum; q_pos = rest % quantum;

    dptr = scull_follow(dev, item);

    if (dptr == NULL || !dptr->data || !dptr->data[s_pos])
        goto out;

    if (count > quantum - q_pos)
        count = quantum - q_pos;

    if (copy_to_user(buf, dptr->data[s_pos] + q_pos, count)) {
        return -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    retval = count;

    out:
        up(&dev->sem);
        return retval;
}

ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    struct scull_dev *dev = filp->private_data;
    struct scull_qset *dptr;
    int quantum = dev->quantum, qset = dev->qset;
    int itemsize = quantum * qset;
    int item, s_pos, q_pos, rest;
    ssize_t retval = -ENOMEM;

    if (down_interruptible(&dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;

    item = (long)*f_pos / itemsize;
    rest = (long)*f_pos % itemsize;
    s_pos = rest / quantum; q_pos = rest % quantum;

    dptr = scull_follow(dev, item);
    if (dptr == NULL)
        goto out;

    if (!dptr->data) {
        dptr->data = kmalloc(sizeof(char *) * dev->qset, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!dptr->data)
            goto out;
        memset(dptr->data, 0, qset * sizeof(char *));
    }
    if (!dptr->data[s_pos]) {
        dptr->data[s_pos] = kmalloc(dev->quantum, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!dptr->data[s_pos])
            goto out;
    }

    if (count > quantum - q_pos)
        count = quantum - q_pos;

    if (copy_from_user(dptr->data[s_pos] + q_pos, buf, count)){
        retval = -EFAULT;
        goto out;
    }

    *f_pos += count;
    retval = count;

    if (dev->size < *f_pos)
        dev->size = *f_pos;

    out:
        up(&dev->sem);
        return retval; 
}

static struct scull_dev scull_devp_array[SCULL_DEV_NO];

struct file_operations scull_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = scull_open,
    .release = scull_release,
    .read = scull_read,
    .write = scull_write
};

static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index) {
    dev_t dev_no = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);
    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Initialized Major: %d, Minor: %d\n", scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    int result = cdev_add(&dev->cdev, dev_no, 1);
    if (result < 0){
        printk(KERN_ERR "scull: Failed to add Major: %d, Minor: %d\n", scull_major, scull_minor + index);
    }
}

static void scull_rm_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Removing cdev\n");
    cdev_del(&dev->cdev);
}

static int __init scull_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Allocating char device...\n");
    
    int result;
    if(scull_major){
        dev = MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor);
        result = register_chrdev_region(dev, scull_nr_devs, "scull");
    } else {
        result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, scull_minor, scull_nr_devs, "scull");
        scull_major = MAJOR(dev);
    }

    if (result < 0) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "scull: can't get major %d\n", scull_major);
        return result;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Major is %d", scull_major);

    for (int i = scull_minor; i < scull_nr_devs; i++) {
        scull_setup_cdev(&scull_devp_array[i], i);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit scull_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Exiting...\n");
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev, scull_nr_devs);
    printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Unregistered device\n");
    for(int i = scull_minor; i < scull_nr_devs; i++) {
        scull_rm_cdev(&scull_devp_array[i]);
        printk(KERN_INFO "scull: Freeing scull_dev %d\n", i);
    }
}

module_init(scull_init);
module_exit(scull_exit);
```

I ran `echo hello > /dev/scull0`. The dmesg logs shows `list_add corruption. prev is NULL` on running the command. When I exit out with `Ctrl + C` and run the command again, the dmesg logs shows 2 errors, the first being a `list_del corruption` and the second being a `list_add corruption`. Here is the dmesg log for the 3 errors:

```
[43170.630743] scull: Opened device 0
[43170.630761] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[43170.630764] list_add corruption. prev is NULL.
[43170.630773] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 57011 at lib/list_debug.c:25 __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.630784] Modules linked in: scull(OE) ntfs3 snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq ccm nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd iwlmvm kvm mac80211 irqbypass mousedev snd_usb_audio joydev crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_rawmidi snd_hda_codec_generic snd_seq_device ledtrig_audio gf128mul snd_hda_codec_hdmi mc ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec libarc4 snd_hda_core btusb btrtl btintel iwlwifi btbcm snd_hwdep btmtk snd_pcm bluetooth cfg80211 snd_timer snd r8169 crypto_simd cryptd ecdh_generic rapl soundcore realtek sp5100_tco mdio_devres k10temp libphy rfkill i2c_piix4 video ccp gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof pcspkr acpi_cpufreq gpio_amdpt wmi mac_hid gpio_generic i2c_dev crypto_user loop fuse dm_mod nfnetlink ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2
[43170.630928]  usbhid nvme nvme_core crc32c_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_auth
[43170.630941] Unloaded tainted modules: scull(OE):13 [last unloaded: scull(OE)]
[43170.630951] CPU: 6 PID: 57011 Comm: bash Tainted: P  R   D W  OE      6.7.0-arch3-1 #1 29ada86f174bb9983ea57568622d66509982ed7e
[43170.630957] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M DS3H WIFI/B450M DS3H WIFI-CF, BIOS F52 01/07/2021
[43170.630960] RIP: 0010:__list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.630966] Code: 75 41 4c 8b 02 49 39 c0 75 4c 48 39 fa 74 60 49 39 f8 74 5b b8 01 00 00 00 e9 fa 05 77 00 48 c7 c7 d0 c7 2a 92 e8 fe 24 a5 ff <0f> 0b 31 c0 e9 e5 05 77 00 48 c7 c7 f8 c7 2a 92 e8 e9 24 a5 ff 0f
[43170.630970] RSP: 0018:ffffad82c1e9bcf8 EFLAGS: 00010082
[43170.630975] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 7fffffffffffffff RCX: 0000000000000027
[43170.630979] RDX: ffff89f40e9a16c8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff89f40e9a16c0
[43170.630982] RBP: ffffad82c1e9bd68 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffad82c1e9bb80
[43170.630985] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffff89f41f32b368 R12: ffffffffc24b87c8
[43170.630989] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffc24b87d0
[43170.630992] FS:  00007747f80d6740(0000) GS:ffff89f40e980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[43170.630997] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[43170.631000] CR2: 0000563ef7be1000 CR3: 00000001c487c000 CR4: 0000000000350ef0
[43170.631004] Call Trace:
[43170.631008]  <TASK>
[43170.631011]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.631016]  ? __warn+0x81/0x130
[43170.631025]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.631030]  ? report_bug+0x171/0x1a0
[43170.631037]  ? prb_read_valid+0x1b/0x30
[43170.631043]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43170.631050]  ? handle_bug+0x3c/0x80
[43170.631057]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x17/0x70
[43170.631063]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1a/0x20
[43170.631074]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.631080]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43170.631084]  __down_common+0x71/0x230
[43170.631095]  down_interruptible+0x52/0x60
[43170.631101]  scull_write+0x4c/0x200 [scull bd55e810425245067618b333771c8e3ae1dc9535]
[43170.631114]  vfs_write+0xf2/0x400
[43170.631127]  ksys_write+0x6f/0xf0
[43170.631135]  do_syscall_64+0x64/0xe0
[43170.631140]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43170.631145]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2b/0x40
[43170.631150]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43170.631155]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43170.631159]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43170.631164]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43170.631169]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43170.631174]  ? exc_page_fault+0x7f/0x180
[43170.631180]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0x76
[43170.631186] RIP: 0033:0x7747f8254034
[43170.631209] Code: c7 00 16 00 00 00 b8 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 35 c3 0d 00 00 74 13 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 54 c3 0f 1f 00 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48
[43170.631213] RSP: 002b:00007fffe0667af8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[43170.631218] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000006 RCX: 00007747f8254034
[43170.631222] RDX: 0000000000000006 RSI: 0000563ef7bde970 RDI: 0000000000000001
[43170.631225] RBP: 0000563ef7bde970 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000001
[43170.631228] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000006
[43170.631232] R13: 00007747f83295c0 R14: 00007747f8326f20 R15: 0000000000000000
[43170.631241]  </TASK>
[43170.631244] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[43188.138981] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[43188.138987] list_del corruption, ffffad82c1e9bd10->next is NULL
[43188.138999] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 57011 at lib/list_debug.c:52 __list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139009] Modules linked in: scull(OE) ntfs3 snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq ccm nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd iwlmvm kvm mac80211 irqbypass mousedev snd_usb_audio joydev crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_rawmidi snd_hda_codec_generic snd_seq_device ledtrig_audio gf128mul snd_hda_codec_hdmi mc ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec libarc4 snd_hda_core btusb btrtl btintel iwlwifi btbcm snd_hwdep btmtk snd_pcm bluetooth cfg80211 snd_timer snd r8169 crypto_simd cryptd ecdh_generic rapl soundcore realtek sp5100_tco mdio_devres k10temp libphy rfkill i2c_piix4 video ccp gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof pcspkr acpi_cpufreq gpio_amdpt wmi mac_hid gpio_generic i2c_dev crypto_user loop fuse dm_mod nfnetlink ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2
[43188.139153]  usbhid nvme nvme_core crc32c_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_auth
[43188.139166] Unloaded tainted modules: scull(OE):13 [last unloaded: scull(OE)]
[43188.139175] CPU: 6 PID: 57011 Comm: bash Tainted: P  R   D W  OE      6.7.0-arch3-1 #1 29ada86f174bb9983ea57568622d66509982ed7e
[43188.139182] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M DS3H WIFI/B450M DS3H WIFI-CF, BIOS F52 01/07/2021
[43188.139186] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139191] Code: 48 8b 01 48 39 f8 75 67 48 8b 72 08 48 39 c6 75 74 b8 01 00 00 00 e9 32 05 77 00 48 89 fe 48 c7 c7 f8 c8 2a 92 e8 33 24 a5 ff <0f> 0b 31 c0 e9 1a 05 77 00 48 89 fe 48 c7 c7 20 c9 2a 92 e8 1b 24
[43188.139196] RSP: 0018:ffffad82c1e9bcf8 EFLAGS: 00010082
[43188.139200] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 7fffffffffffffff RCX: 0000000000000027
[43188.139204] RDX: ffff89f40e9a16c8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff89f40e9a16c0
[43188.139208] RBP: ffffad82c1e9bd68 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffad82c1e9bb80
[43188.139211] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffff89f41f32b368 R12: ffffffffc24b87c8
[43188.139214] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff89f270b10000
[43188.139217] FS:  00007747f80d6740(0000) GS:ffff89f40e980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[43188.139222] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[43188.139225] CR2: 00007740023bd698 CR3: 00000001c487c000 CR4: 0000000000350ef0
[43188.139229] Call Trace:
[43188.139233]  <TASK>
[43188.139236]  ? __list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139241]  ? __warn+0x81/0x130
[43188.139248]  ? __list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139253]  ? report_bug+0x171/0x1a0
[43188.139261]  ? prb_read_valid+0x1b/0x30
[43188.139267]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43188.139274]  ? handle_bug+0x3c/0x80
[43188.139280]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x17/0x70
[43188.139286]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1a/0x20
[43188.139298]  ? __list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139304]  ? __list_del_entry_valid_or_report+0x5d/0xe0
[43188.139308]  __down_common+0xdb/0x230
[43188.139318]  down_interruptible+0x52/0x60
[43188.139325]  scull_write+0x4c/0x200 [scull bd55e810425245067618b333771c8e3ae1dc9535]
[43188.139338]  vfs_write+0xf2/0x400
[43188.139350]  ksys_write+0x6f/0xf0
[43188.139358]  do_syscall_64+0x64/0xe0
[43188.139363]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43188.139368]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2b/0x40
[43188.139373]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43188.139378]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43188.139382]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43188.139387]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43188.139392]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43188.139397]  ? exc_page_fault+0x7f/0x180
[43188.139403]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0x76
[43188.139409] RIP: 0033:0x7747f8254034
[43188.139432] Code: c7 00 16 00 00 00 b8 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 35 c3 0d 00 00 74 13 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 54 c3 0f 1f 00 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48
[43188.139436] RSP: 002b:00007fffe0667af8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[43188.139442] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000006 RCX: 00007747f8254034
[43188.139445] RDX: 0000000000000006 RSI: 0000563ef7bde970 RDI: 0000000000000001
[43188.139448] RBP: 0000563ef7bde970 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000001
[43188.139452] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000006
[43188.139455] R13: 00007747f83295c0 R14: 00007747f8326f20 R15: 0000000000000000
[43188.139464]  </TASK>
[43188.139467] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[43188.139503] scull: Released device 0
[43189.594736] scull: Opened device 0
[43189.594753] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[43189.594757] list_add corruption. prev is NULL.
[43189.594766] WARNING: CPU: 6 PID: 57011 at lib/list_debug.c:25 __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.594777] Modules linked in: scull(OE) ntfs3 snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq ccm nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_uvm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) vfat fat intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd kvm_amd iwlmvm kvm mac80211 irqbypass mousedev snd_usb_audio joydev crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic snd_usbmidi_lib snd_ump snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_rawmidi snd_hda_codec_generic snd_seq_device ledtrig_audio gf128mul snd_hda_codec_hdmi mc ghash_clmulni_intel sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec libarc4 snd_hda_core btusb btrtl btintel iwlwifi btbcm snd_hwdep btmtk snd_pcm bluetooth cfg80211 snd_timer snd r8169 crypto_simd cryptd ecdh_generic rapl soundcore realtek sp5100_tco mdio_devres k10temp libphy rfkill i2c_piix4 video ccp gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof pcspkr acpi_cpufreq gpio_amdpt wmi mac_hid gpio_generic i2c_dev crypto_user loop fuse dm_mod nfnetlink ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2
[43189.594923]  usbhid nvme nvme_core crc32c_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_auth
[43189.594936] Unloaded tainted modules: scull(OE):13 [last unloaded: scull(OE)]
[43189.594945] CPU: 6 PID: 57011 Comm: bash Tainted: P  R   D W  OE      6.7.0-arch3-1 #1 29ada86f174bb9983ea57568622d66509982ed7e
[43189.594951] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450M DS3H WIFI/B450M DS3H WIFI-CF, BIOS F52 01/07/2021
[43189.594955] RIP: 0010:__list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.594960] Code: 75 41 4c 8b 02 49 39 c0 75 4c 48 39 fa 74 60 49 39 f8 74 5b b8 01 00 00 00 e9 fa 05 77 00 48 c7 c7 d0 c7 2a 92 e8 fe 24 a5 ff <0f> 0b 31 c0 e9 e5 05 77 00 48 c7 c7 f8 c7 2a 92 e8 e9 24 a5 ff 0f
[43189.594964] RSP: 0018:ffffad82c1e9bd28 EFLAGS: 00010086
[43189.594970] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 7fffffffffffffff RCX: 0000000000000027
[43189.594973] RDX: ffff89f40e9a16c8 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff89f40e9a16c0
[43189.594977] RBP: ffffad82c1e9bd98 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffad82c1e9bbb0
[43189.594980] R10: 0000000000000003 R11: ffff89f41f32b368 R12: ffffffffc24b87c8
[43189.594983] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffc24b87d0
[43189.594987] FS:  00007747f80d6740(0000) GS:ffff89f40e980000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[43189.594991] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[43189.594995] CR2: 00007740023bd698 CR3: 00000001c487c000 CR4: 0000000000350ef0
[43189.594999] Call Trace:
[43189.595003]  <TASK>
[43189.595006]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.595011]  ? __warn+0x81/0x130
[43189.595020]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.595026]  ? report_bug+0x171/0x1a0
[43189.595033]  ? prb_read_valid+0x1b/0x30
[43189.595038]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595046]  ? handle_bug+0x3c/0x80
[43189.595052]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x17/0x70
[43189.595058]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1a/0x20
[43189.595069]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.595075]  ? __list_add_valid_or_report+0x42/0xa0
[43189.595079]  __down_common+0x71/0x230
[43189.595090]  down_interruptible+0x52/0x60
[43189.595096]  scull_write+0x4c/0x200 [scull bd55e810425245067618b333771c8e3ae1dc9535]
[43189.595109]  vfs_write+0xf2/0x400
[43189.595117]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595122]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2b/0x40
[43189.595127]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595131]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43189.595136]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595141]  ? filp_flush+0x52/0x80
[43189.595149]  ksys_write+0x6f/0xf0
[43189.595157]  do_syscall_64+0x64/0xe0
[43189.595162]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43189.595166]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2b/0x40
[43189.595171]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595175]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43189.595180]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595184]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2b/0x40
[43189.595189]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[43189.595194]  ? do_syscall_64+0x70/0xe0
[43189.595199]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0x76
[43189.595205] RIP: 0033:0x7747f8254034
[43189.595228] Code: c7 00 16 00 00 00 b8 ff ff ff ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 80 3d 35 c3 0d 00 00 74 13 b8 01 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 54 c3 0f 1f 00 48 83 ec 28 48 89 54 24 18 48
[43189.595232] RSP: 002b:00007fffe0667af8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001
[43189.595237] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000006 RCX: 00007747f8254034
[43189.595241] RDX: 0000000000000006 RSI: 0000563ef7bde970 RDI: 0000000000000001
[43189.595244] RBP: 0000563ef7bde970 R08: 0000000000000073 R09: 0000000000000001
[43189.595247] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000006
[43189.595250] R13: 00007747f83295c0 R14: 00007747f8326f20 R15: 0000000000000000
[43189.595260]  </TASK>
[43189.595263] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

I tested to see if it was an issue with the `scull_follow()` function by removing everything in the write function and just using `down_interruptible()` and `printk()` to see if that was the case. I was encountering the same issue. I am hypothesising that the issue has something to do with the semaphore. Please guide me on what to do.

Comment: I don't see in your code **initialization** of the semaphore `sem`.

Comment: To expand on @Tsyvarev's comment, you need `sema_init(&dev->sem, 1);` in `scull_setup_cdev()` to initialize the semaphore `sem` for use as a mutex. LDD3 is really old and these days (since kernel version 2.6.16) you would replace the `struct semaphore` with a `struct mutex` and use the corresponding mutex functions instead of the semaphore functions.

Comment: I think you also use fields of scull_dev uninitialized